# What condenser can be used for simple distillation?

Tags: home-experiment

I think I need some distilling (boiling) and collection flasks and a 3-way adapter with a thermometer.  I was thinking of using an open vacuum adaptor to join the lower end of the condenser to the receiving flask.  Does this sound ok?  And if so, what kind of condenser should I use?

Comment: You generally don't need a vacuum to distill unless the BP is fairly high. If it is a fairly volatile liquid then a lot can get sucked down to the pump oil. Using water to pull the vacuum has other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds good.  Here's a drawing of the set up.  I'd use a water-cooled condenser.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That sounds fine. You only need the open vacuum adaptor if you're using a sealed distillation setup and you have cause to worry about the pressure while distilling.

I use a basic [distillation apparatus](http://www.sanjosescientific.com/catalog/4002.jpg) with a Graham condenser and a Kjeldahl distillation bulb.  Currently, I skip the three-way adapter with the thermometer because I'm just doing basic distillations and while I can seal mine I generally don't because I'm not worried about my distillate evaporating .

[image: basic distillation apparatus]

Comment: This setup looks early 19th century and will blow in your face at the first boiling retardation.